# How to rename a variable in R without copying the object?

Tags: r

I have a huge data frame loaded in global environment in R named `df`. How can I rename the data frame without copying the data frame by assigning it to another symbol and remove the original one?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2717853/489704) related answer and its comments.

Comment: You can also read [**this thread**](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-March/156028.html).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

R is smart enough not to make a copy if the variable is the same, so just go ahead, reassign and `rm()` the original.

Example:

```
x <- 1:10
tracemem(x)
# [1] "<0000000017181EA8>"
y <- x
tracemem(y)
# [1] "<0000000017181EA8>"
```

As we can see both objects point to the same address. R makes a new copy in the memory if one of them is modified, i.e.: 2 objects are not identical anymore.

```
# Now change one of the vectors
y[2] <- 3
# tracemem[0x0000000017181ea8 -> 0x0000000017178c68]: 
# tracemem[0x0000000017178c68 -> 0x0000000012ebe3b0]: 
tracemem(x)
# [1] "<0000000017181EA8>"
tracemem(y)
# [1] "<0000000012EBE3B0>"
```

Related post: [How do I rename an R object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717757)

Comment: +1, but I think you could reinforce this answer with some "proof" (even with using something as simple as `x <- 1:10; tracemem(x); y <- x; tracemem(y); rm(x)`.

Comment: good point, and that is a nice way to show the lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

There is a function called `mv` in the `gdata` package.

```
library(gdata)

x <- data.frame(A = 1:100, B = 101:200, C = 201:300)

tracemem(x)
"<0000000024EA66F8>"

mv(from = "x", to = "y")

tracemem(y)
"<0000000024EA66F8>"
```

You will notice that the output from `tracemem` is identical for `x` and `y`. Looking at the code of `mv`, you will see that it assigns the object to the environment in scope and then removes the old object. This is quite similar to the approach C8H10N4O2 used (although `mv` is for a single object), but at least the function is convenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

To apply the accepted answer to many objects, you could use a loop of `assign(new_name, get(old_name))` followed by `rm(list= old_names)`.  For example, if you wanted to replace `old_df`,`old_x`,`old_y`, ... with `new_df`, `new_x`...

```
for (obj_old_name in ls(pattern='old_')){
  assign(sub('old_','new_',obj_old_name), get(obj_old_name))
}
rm(list=ls(pattern='old_'))
```