# Dynamically rename a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I want to rename an existing data frame to the name in a variable.  Any ideas are appreciated.

```
rtbl <- load("clarktestjunk.RData")

datasetname = "specialdata" # passed in by the user
rename(rtbl,datasetname) # this is not the correct command

specialdata # this is how I want to reference the data set down stream.
```

Comment: Related posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951811, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717757

Comment: I figured it out.


eval(parse(text=paste(datasetname,"<-rtbl")))

Comment: "If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question." -- Thomas Lumley R-help (February 2005). Also, see [What specifically are the dangers of eval(parse(…))?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse)

Answer (score 2):

This is a way (which works not only for data frames):

```
old.name=data.frame(a=1:5,b=6:10)
assign("new.name",old.name)

> new.name
  a  b
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10
```

Answer (score 2):

An object can't be renamed in the way your pseudo-code implies. You *can* assign the contents of the the data.frame to a new object with a known name. (See @Wave's solution with `assign`.) But the original object will still exist.

```
rm(list=ls())
data(cars)
ls()
# [1] "cars"
assign("renamed_cars", cars)
ls()
# [1] "cars"         "renamed_cars"
rm(cars)
ls()
# [1] "renamed_cars"
```