# Assign a variable to a string, using only a string containing that variable's name

Tags: r, string, rename

I have many `.rda` file, which themselves are correctly named, however the variables they each contain (only one per file) are incorrectly labelled. I am attempting to load them into the workspace one by one, rename them to the correct variable name and then save them into a new folder, using the same file name that each file already has.

My attempt is below and the problem is that in the step using `assign`, it seems to only be assign the actual name of the variable I'd like to be reassigning. So when I then save this and load it again, I have a variable holding a string, not the actual results.

```
input_folder <- "/path/to/input_folder/"
output_folder <- "/path/to/output_folder/"

## What I know
A <- "data_chunk"                     #input name
B <- "results_Lag.1"                  #variable/data name in workspace
C <- "results.L1.trad_small.rda"  #file saved name

load(paste0(input_folder, C))            #load the data into the workspace

to_save <- substr(C, 1, nchar(C)-4)     #desired new name in workspace. the -4 loses ".rda"

## Four variations on how to re-assign the data
assign(to_save, B)
assign(to_save, get(B))
assign(to_save, as.name(B))
assign(to_save, eval(parse(B)))

## Save the data with new vairable name to new folder
save(list = to_save, file = paste0(output_folder, C))
```

As you can see from the three variations, I have seen several ways ([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081982/how-to-assign-values-to-dynamic-names-variables-in-r)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717757/how-do-i-rename-an-r-object?lq=1)[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057006/getting-strings-recognized-as-variable-names-in-r)) to call a variable from the workspace using a string.

<strike>The first three simply save my my string `B` as the variable</strike>, while the last variations using `eval(parse())` returns an error:

```
> assign(to_save, eval(parse(B)))
Error in file(filename, "r") : cannot open the connection
Calls: assign -> eval -> parse -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r") :
  cannot open file 'glm_results_Lag.1': No such file or directory
Calls: assign -> eval -> parse -> file
```

If I call `get(B)` in the console, it **does** return the contents of the variable as expected.

### EDIT

As @joran says in the comments, the second variant does produce the expected result, saving the data to the specified string:

```
assign(to_save, get(B))
```

The size of the new object on disk, however, is different to that of the loaded file (As i mention in the comments).

I have no explanation for this...

Comment: `assign(...,get())` works as you seem to want it to when I try it myself.

Comment: It seems to work within the workspace, you are correct, however when I then try to save it, the object in my folder only contains the string. Is there a mistake in the line `save(list = to_save, file = paste0(output_folder, C))` ? The `file` argument is sound, at least the file holding the string shows up in the new folder.

Comment: That part works fine for me too.

Comment: @joran - By Jove, you're right  :)   I must not have checked that one specifically by loading it. In my folder it's size is 87 bytes, whereas the original file i loaded was 33kb. Loaded into the workspace, they are both 1.9Mb. Any idea why this is the case?  Do you recommend I delete this post?